# Remove ASDM from ASA

Tags: cisco-asa

Hi im trying to remove ASDM from my ASA.

Ive deleted the bin file from the flash drive and did a config factory-default
But i can still connect to the ASA through ASDM.

Is it posible to remove it? How?

I would like to uninstall ASDM from ASA.

Comment: Remove it?  Does specifying which hosts/networks from Device Management not work.  You can remove or limit access from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *did* uninstall it... *from the ASA*. All that's on the ASA is installer packages. Once you've used ASDM from the firewall (https... *Install ASDM Launcher*), then you have ASDM on your PC; it doesn't need anything from the ASA at that point. As long as the web server is enabled on the ASA, an installed instance of ASDM can connect to it.

Answer (score -2):

Try `no http server enable` , this should prevent the ASA from accepting ASDM connections.

Comment: Hi. I know i can limit who can access to asa. But i want to unistall asdm from asa. If thats posible.